# TableLayout, Text-Align to right

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, alignment

once more: me.

I have a TableLayout (http://imgur.com/XYdcg) for my "SingleItemAdvancedView" how i like to call it ;)
The thing is, I want the data [the TextViews which don't have string *Lbl as android:text set] (so **NOT** the description like : "name:" , "id:" etc.) to be displayed on the right side of the whole display, not like it's now ( they are displayed right next to the left table-column). I tried to align the layout to the right side, as well as only the text (with layout_gravity and gravity only). everything didn't work. My widths are all set to fill_parent , so I simply don't understand why. Help needed! Thanks!

My XML for the activity looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/idLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/itemidv" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/nameLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/namev" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/amountLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/amountv" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/unitLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/unitv" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/ppuLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/ppuv" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/totalLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/totalv" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/commentLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/commentv" />
  </TableRow>
   <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/enterqrLbl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/qrcodev" />
  </TableRow>
   <Button android:text="@string/delete"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:id="@+id/deleteItemBtn"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:onClick="btnListener" />
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add android:stretchColumns="0" to TableLayout. So you would have something like this:

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:stretchColumns="0">
```

If you want both columns to stretch equally you could use '*' instead of '0'.